# CSS class doesnt work after PHP script

Tags: php, html, css, mysql

I've been applying some CSS styles to my HTML elements through their classes with an external CSS document. It works well but after I apply a PHP script to get some MySQL elements the styles doesn't affect the elements anymore.

```
<div class="col s12 m5">
<h4 class="red-text center-align">Sitios de interés</h4>

<?php
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM `sitiosintereslink`";
  $rs = mysqli_query($conexion, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($conexion)); 
  $fila = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rs);
  do{?>

<div class="card col l4 m6 s6">
  <a href="<?php echo $fila['direccion']; ?>">
    <div class="card-image" align="center"><img src="<?php echo $fila['imagen']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $fila['comentario']; ?>"  class="img-responsive"></div>
    <div class="card-action" align="center"><span style="font-size: 15"><?php echo $fila['titulo']; ?></span></div>
  </a>
</div>
<?php }while ($fila = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rs));?>
```

The CSS document with the styles for this classes:

```
.card-image {
    width:65% !important;
}
.card-action {
    height: 115px !important;
}
```

If I apply the styles directly in the elements it works, but well, that's not the way to do it.

Comment: have you checked that your stylesheet is linked correctly?

Comment: It is, like a said, it works well before the script with other elements.

Comment: What is not happening that should happen? Your code has no errors!

Comment: You have 2x mysqli_fetch_assoc... just use the one in the do-while.

Comment: Did you check the source view with the PHP script running ?

Comment: inspect the element in chrome. Find out what is taking priority. I would probably guess it as being the img-responsive class. Sounds like a CSS Specificity problem.

Comment: What is the resulting html?

Comment: You can not write `do-while` loop in PHP like that. If you want `HTML` inside PHP script then you enclosed it within `echo`.

Comment: I think it is taking the prioprity of the Materialize CSS classes, but that doesn't happen before with other Materialize elements. When I inspect it in chrome it shows this: element.style {
} .card .card-image {
    position: relative;
}
materialize.css:2546
*, *:before, *:after {
    -webkit-box-sizing: inherit;
    box-sizing: inherit;
}
div[Attributes Style] {
    text-align: -webkit-center;
}
user agent stylesheet
div {
    display: block;
}

Comment: I changed the double mysqli_fetch_assoc, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think that could be the problem. There is a syntactic problem:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `sitiosintereslink`;";
```

Look at your code this isn't clear for someone. I read your code and I can't understand because it isn't english and that is a chaos. Use some form in your code.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what type of server you are using. Because what I can see so is your code just fine. If it is a local server that you have set up for working on it and you are using http://localhost

Then I would recommend that you try and look with http://127.0.0.1
It can be that your cache has frozen. Happens to me as well sometimes. So I switches between those two addresses. And if that isn't enough, then try to add a div or just a paragraph with some text and style it. If it works then try to make it so it shows something first. Like a if-statement